# Flutter class error , Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to create generic API response class in flutter application and I'm getting this error

```
class ApiResponse<T> {
  Status status;
  T data;
  String message;

  ApiResponse.loading(this.message) : status = Status.LOADING;
  ApiResponse.completed(this.data) : status = Status.COMPLETED;
  ApiResponse.error(this.message) : status = Status.ERROR;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "Status : $status \n Message : $message \n Data : $data";
  }
}

enum Status { LOADING, COMPLETED, ERROR }
```

IDE complains about below error

**Non-nullable instance field 'data' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'**

Could anyone tell me what is wrong wiht my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because like the error says, `data` field has a non-nullable type `T`. If you want to allow `null` for the field `data`, you will need to make its type nullable by putting a `?` like so.

```
T? data;
```

Similarly, you will also need to make `message` field nullable.

```
String? message;
```

To see other ways you can go about this and to understand null-safety better, I'd suggest reading [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).